# Insert large amount of data in table with index in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, indexing, airflow

I have a table `tbl` in Postgres with 50 million rows. The `tbl` has an index on `column_1` and there are a lot of queries to this table like

```
select * from tbl
where column_1 = 'value'
```

Each query returns 0-30 rows, 10 on avarage.

Once a day I completely update data in table. The query is like

```
delete from tbl;
insert into tbl
select * from tbl_2;
commit;
```

The challenge I face is the query runs too long: about 2-3 hours. It's probably because of index. Is there a way to speed up the data update and allow user to query `tbl` while it's being updated.
If this is important - the update process is run in python Airflow and the queries come from python web app.

Comment: As we did in the Oracle days: Delete the index, Load the data, ReCreate the index. That was by far the fastest method.

Comment: But when index is deleted the queries run too slow. That is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you looked at [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a copy of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_new (LIKE tbl);

INSERT INTO tbl_new
SELECT * FROM tbl_2;
```

Then, create all required indexes on that table. Once you are done, switch tables:

```
BEGIN;

DROP TABLE tbl;

ALTER TABLE tbl_new RENAME TO tbl;

COMMIT;
```

That will be fast.

Comment: New table should probably be created with (LIKE tbl INCLUDING ALL) or INCLUDING INDEXES to match the original. At least a primary key and the index on column_1 should be created after the insert (this would be faster).

Comment: @LauriK The point is *not* to create the indexes before loading for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing references this table, [Laurenz'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) [Indiana Jones](https://media.tenor.com/eqLNYv0A9TQAAAAC/swap-indiana-jones.gif)-style [golden idol swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438228/5298879) should be enough

```sql
create table tbl_tmp (like tbl); 
insert into tbl_tmp table tbl;
create temp table index_definitions as select indexdef 
  from pg_indexes where schemaname='public' and tablename='tbl';
begin; drop table tbl; alter table tbl_tmp rename to tbl; commit;

do $p$ declare indexdef_ text; 
begin for indexdef_ in select indexdef from index_definitions loop
          execute indexdef_;
      end loop;
      drop table index_definitions;
end $p$;
```

This also transfers the index definitions from the previous version of the table.

If you are superuser and in mood for hacky solutions, you can disable the indexes for the time of your insert. This might be useful if the table is referenced by other objects because you keep the original table, whereas the swap loses the previous one and replaces it with a new one, so all references break and need to be re-established:

```sql
begin work;

update pg_index set indisvalid=false, indisready=false, indislive=false
where indrelid = 'tbl'::regclass;

delete from tbl;
insert into tbl table tbl_2;

update pg_index set indisvalid=true, indisready=true, indislive=true
where indrelid = 'tbl'::regclass;
reindex table tbl; 
commit work;
```

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438149/insert-large-amount-of-data-in-table-with-index-in-postgres#comment136520523_77438149) by [@JonSG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218663/jonsg), you might want to consider a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) that you'd just refresh, or even [pg_ivm](https://github.com/sraoss/pg_ivm).